# How to zoom in the Image by ROI in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have two images. I want to see the more detail in special region (ROI). Hence, I will draw a red rectangular and zoom in it as original size (256 by 256) and display in second row as my below expected result. Could you help me to solve it in MATLAB? This is my current code

```
 Img1 = imread('peppers.png');
 Img2 = imread('coins.png');
 Img1=imresize(Img1,[256 256]);
 Img2=imresize(Img2,[256 256]);
 %%Draw rectangle
 subplot(221);imshow(Img1); rectangle('Position',[100 50 20 20], 'LineWidth',2, 'EdgeColor','r');
 subplot(222);imshow(Img2);rectangle('Position',[100 50 20 20], 'LineWidth',2, 'EdgeColor','r');
 %% zoom in image
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (when the images appears, use your `mouse` to select a region of interest):

```
 Img1 = imread('peppers.png');
 Img1=imresize(Img1,[256 256]);

 f=figure;
 imshow(Img1);
 rect = getrect(f); %//select roi with mouse
 Img1_roi = Img1( rect(2) : (rect(2)+rect(4)) , rect(1) : (rect(1)+rect(3)) , : ); %//store roi in matrix

 Img2 = imread('coins.png');
 Img2= imresize(Img2,[256 256]); 

 f=figure;
 imshow(Img2);
 rect = getrect(f); %//select roi with mouse
 Img2_roi = Img2( rect(2) : (rect(2)+rect(4)) , rect(1) : (rect(1)+rect(3)) , : );  %//store roi in matrix

 %//Plot
 subplot(2,2,1)
 imshow(Img1)
 subplot(2,2,2)
 imshow(Img2)
 subplot(2,2,3)
 imshow(Img1_roi)
 subplot(2,2,4)
 imshow(Img2_roi)
```

Comment: @user8264 instead of `rect = getrect(f)`, fill in `rect` by yourself in code. For example, if I want to crop out a region starting from `(100,100)` of `width = 80` and `height = 90`, set `rect = [100 100 80 90]`. The rest of the code remains the same

Comment: It works well. I just have other question. Do you know how to draw the bounding box for third image (Img1_roi) and last image. I want draw the red color which covers these image as update question

Comment: @user8264 Add this line below `imshow(Img1_roi)`: `rectangle('Position',[1 1 90 60], 'LineWidth',2, 'EdgeColor','r')`, where `90` and `60` are the `width` and `height` of the roi image.